# Paste values into website search bar VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel

I am working on automating a workflow whereby I navigate to a specific website (http://www.boxofficemojo.com/) and paste a value into the website's search bar.  I am having trouble interacting with the website search bar in VBA.

the search bar has the following HTML code:

```
<form name="searchbox" action="/search/q.php" method="POST">
    <input name="q" style="width: 90px; font-weight: bold;" type="text"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Search...">
</form>
```

The code command I have right now that doesn't seem to be working is below.  I want to paste the excel values from cell c3 into the search bar and then submit.

```
objIE.Document.getElementByName("q").Value = Sheets("2016").Range("c3").Value
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested, this works for me:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, Doc As HTMLDocument
    Dim oSearch As HTMLDivElement

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://www.boxofficemojo.com/"
        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Set Doc = IE.Document
    End With

    Set oSearch = Doc.getElementsByClassName("nl_link")(3)
    Set oSearch = oSearch.getElementsByTagName("input")(0)
    oSearch.Value = "test"

    Doc.forms(0).submit

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! as a quick follow up, how would I then click on the search button? the search button HTML code is: *<input type="submit" value="Search...">

Comment: @n1xn1x Updated answer to include a method for submitting the form.

Comment: The only problem I'm having with that code is the following line: Set Doc = IE.Document

it is giving me an "object required" error..any ideas?

my whole code is:
Dim objIE As New InternetExplorer
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Dim oSearch As HTMLDivElement

With objIE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "http://www.boxofficemojo.com/"
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Set Doc = IE.Document
End With

Set oSearch = Doc.getElementsByClassName("nl_link")(3)
etc.....

Comment: @n1xn1x I see in the supplied code, you have two IE objects: `IE` and `objIE`. You need to use the one you have declared as your Internet Explorer object. Also, add `Option Explicit` to the top of your module.

Answer (score 1):

> objIE.Document.getElementByName("q").Value = Sheets("2016").Range("c3").Value

I believe you want to use "getElementsByName()" which returns a collection of elements. Assuming the first element:

```
objIE.Document.getElementsByName("q")[0].Value = Sheets("2016").Range("c3").Value
```

Comment: Thank you!  as a quick follow up, how would I then click on the search button?  the search button HTML code is:
<*input type="submit" value="Search...">